# Understanding iOS error messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am very new to iOS programming and have been thrown in the deep end with an application I am working on. My application was working fine but then this error message started appearing even when I hadn't changed the code. Could someone explain what is going on here?

The error message is different sometimes with the "**_NSCFDictionary**" being "**OS_dispatch_queue_**" or an "**_NSMallocBlock**" etc. It never seems to be the same twice. I have tried cleaning the project to no avail.

```
2016-05-24 13:28:12.761 dam[1357:648017] -[__NSCFDictionary isContentAvailable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1570c52d0
2016-05-24 13:28:12.768 dam[1357:648017] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.08 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *)      
(GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: -[__NSCFDictionary isContentAvailable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1570c52d0
2016-05-24 13:28:13.753 dam[1357:648017] -[__NSCFDictionary isContentAvailable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1570c52d0
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

EDIT:

After looking through my code it seems the error is coming from Tapjoy SDK. The error seems to occur in the is prepared method with `_p = 0`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MovieReward6005.h"

#import <Tapjoy/Tapjoy.h>

@interface MovieReward6005()<TJPlacementDelegate, TJCVideoAdDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong)UIViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL test_flg;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString* placement_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong)TJPlacement* p;

@end

@implementation MovieReward6005

- (id)init{
NSLog(@"MovieReward6005 init");
if(!self){
    self = [super init];

    [Tapjoy startSession];

    // Add an observer for when a user has successfully earned currency.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(showEarnedCurrencyAlert:)
                                                 name:TJC_CURRENCY_EARNED_NOTIFICATION
                                               object:nil];

    // Best Practice: We recommend calling getCurrencyBalance as often as possible so the user’s balance is always up-to-date.
    [Tapjoy getCurrencyBalance];
}
return self;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 *  @param data
 */
-(void)setData:(NSDictionary *)data{
NSLog(@"MovieReward6005 setData start");
NSLog(@"data : %@",data);

self.viewController = [data objectForKey:@"displayViewContorller"];
NSLog(@"MovieReward6005 connectSetting start");
_p = nil;
//Set up success and failure notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(tjcConnectSuccess:)
                                             name:TJC_CONNECT_SUCCESS
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(tjcConnectFail:)
                                             name:TJC_CONNECT_FAILED
                                           object:nil];

BOOL test_flg = [[data objectForKey:@"test_flg"] boolValue];
//    test_flg = YES;
[Tapjoy setDebugEnabled:test_flg];
NSString* connectStr = [data objectForKey:@"sdk_key"];
self.placement_id = [data objectForKey:@"placement_id"];
//The Tapjoy connect call
[Tapjoy connect:connectStr];
NSLog(@"MovieReward6005 connectSetting end");
}

/**
 *  
 */
-(void)startAd
{
//NSLog(@"MovieReward6005 startAd");
if (!self.viewController) {
    return;
}

[Tapjoy setVideoAdDelegate:self];
_p = [TJPlacement placementWithName:_placement_id delegate:self];
_p.adapterVersion = @"1.0.0";
[_p requestContent];

}

-(BOOL)isPrepared{
NSLog(@"MovieReward6005 isPrepared");
NSLog(@"_p.isContentAvailable : %d",_p.isContentAvailable);
return _p.isContentAvailable;
}
```

Comment: It means a method called isContentAvailable is being called on an object of type NSCFDictionary, but an NSCFDictionary doesn't have a method called that. Does isContentAvailable also always appear in the error message when it changes?

Comment: Most likely you are using an object that has been deallocated. Does the project use ARC or older style release/autorelease? In any event, the first thing I would do is edit the Run Scheme to enable Diagnostics / Zombie Objects and Address Sanitizer.

Comment: @ThePumpingLama yes isContentAvailable always appears

Comment: Showing your code might be usefull.

Comment: @Reconquistador I have added the area I think is causing the issue. This issue wasnt happening before and the code hasnt changed.

Comment: Conform where the error is occurring as the first step. The code already has logging, see which was the last line logged before the error happened to narrow it down, add more logging if necessary. You can also try adding an exception breakpoint in Xcode - google for how to do this, its easy to find guides.

Answer (score 0):

You have `p` defined as a property but you are accessing the underlying variable `_p`, which doesn't use the getter/setter functions that a property provides.

I suggest changing all your references to `_p` into `self.p` for better memory management.

Answer (score -1):

Error is telling you, that Dictionary does not know method 'isContentAvailable'. This is true, unless you create some category (which I believe you have not made). In your code that you have showed us, there is this methid called on 'p', which shall be of class TJPlacement. If this error is really fired in the code you have shown there, then real cause lies in other part of the code. It seems, that 'p' is not of class TJPlacement as it shall be, but of class NSDictionary. Try to chek that and to find why it is of this class.